# how to add button to UISearchBar

Tags: iphone

[image]

I need to implement like above figure... How to add button to UISearch Bar.

its for iphone.

Please help me out.

@ thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose you need to create a class(MyScearchBar) whose parent class will be UISearchBar.
I that class

```
 -(void)layoutSubviews
{

self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
textField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
textField.delegate = self;
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(90,5,250,31)];
textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

settings=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[settings setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 50)];
[self addSubview:settings];

}
```

your code instead of using UIsearchbar, use the new class name you have created(MySearchBar).

```
ie MySearchBar search=[[MySearchBar alloc]init];
```

All the best.

Comment: Is there any way to replicate this same behavior but using UISearchDisplayController?