# How do you add a button to a UISearchBar within UITableview's header?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

My question is different than [how to add button to UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458030/how-to-add-button-to-uisearchbar) , as he is adding the searchbar in a navigation bar and I need to use a table view for the same.

I am working in an app in which I need to add a button beside the search box in UISearchbar. I tried to find a solution for this but the only way I've found is using UINavigationBar. However, I need to animate the searchbar on begin and end of an editing event, so putting it on a navigation bar doesn't meet my needs.

I have put my search bar in my UITableview's header view so that it can scroll with the table view. It works fine and animates as expected and of course scrolls, except for the button beside the search box.

Is there any other way to add a button beside the search box in UISearchBar?

Comment: You can add a small toolbar beside the searchBar. Add a barbutton in toolbar...like take the width of search bar as 200 and toolbar as 120 in iphone.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper, I can't add the tool bar in my Table's header view

Comment: @Atulkumar - There's no need to highlight every keyword in the question. In fact, some people find this annoying: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back . Could you refrain from suggesting edits just to add these highlights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can add them both on a view and return the view in

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

method.

Comment: thanks its working fine. I was adding by IB and that's why it was not working as per my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

IB should work as well. Just make sure to connect the UISearchbar delegate to the View Controller and use its delegate methods from the VC, or alternatively use IBactions called from your searchBar to pass your data and actions to the VC logic. Nelson